# AWS - How to get boto3 detach volume state

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a script that is encrypting instance volumes that are not currently encrypted. The last two steps are to detach the unencrypted volume and attach the new encrypted volume. It works if I use `time.sleep(180)` to create a wait period before the attach volume process starts. This would be more efficient if it could ensure the previous step completed successfully. That is why I am using a while statement.

```
import boto3, json, sys, time
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("A profile parameter is required.")
    profile = input("Enter a profile name: ")
    boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name=profile)
else:
    profile = (sys.argv[1])
    boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name=profile)

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[sys.argv[2]])

for i in instances:
    i_name = "unnamed"
    r = i.root_device_name
    i_az = i.placement['AvailabilityZone']
    if i.tags is None:
        continue
    for tag in i.tags:
        if tag['Key'] == "Name":
            i_name = tag['Value']
        if tag["Key"] == 'Costcenter':
            i_div = tag['Value']
    print('\n')
    print(' {}'.format(i.id))
    for x in i.block_device_mappings:
        volumes = i.volumes.all()
        d = x.get('DeviceName')
        e = x.get('Ebs')
        g = e.get('VolumeId')
        for v in volumes:
            if v.id == g:
                f = v.size
                h = v.encrypted
                if h == False:
                    snap_name = i_name + "_" + d
                    ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[i.id]).stop()
                    while i.state['Name'] != 'stopped':
                        time.sleep(10)
                        i.load()
                    snap = ec2.create_snapshot(
                        VolumeId = g,
                        TagSpecifications=[
                            {
                                'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
                                'Tags' : [
                                    {
                                        'Key': 'Name',
                                        'Value': snap_name
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'Key': 'Backup',
                                        'Value': 'Daily'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'Key': 'Costcenter',
                                        'Value': i_div
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                        ],
                    Description = 'Snapshot of volume ({})'.format(v.id)
                    )
                    snap.load()
                    while snap.state != 'completed':
                        time.sleep(10)
                        snap.load()
                    snap_id = snap.id
                    vol = ec2.create_volume(
                        AvailabilityZone = i_az,
                        Encrypted = True,
                        SnapshotId = snap_id,
                        VolumeType = 'gp3',
                        TagSpecifications=[
                            {
                                'ResourceType': 'volume',
                                'Tags': [
                                    {
                                        'Key': 'Name',
                                        'Value': i_name
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'Key': 'Backup',
                                        'Value': 'Daily'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'Key': 'Costcenter',
                                        'Value': i_div
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                        ]
                    )
                    while vol.state != 'available':
                        time.sleep(10)
                        vol.load()
                    vol_id = vol.id
                    volume = ec2.Volume(v.id)
                    detach_vol = volume.detach_from_instance(
                        Device = d,
                        Force = False,
                        InstanceId = i.id,
                        VolumeId = v.id,
                        DryRun = False
                    )
                    while detach_vol != 'detached':
                        time.sleep(10)
                        detach_vol.load()
                    
                    vol_id = vol.id
                    attach_vol = volume.attach_to_instance(
                        VolumeId = vol_id,
                        Device = d,
                        InstanceId = i.id,
                        DryRun = False
                    )
                    
                    while attach_vol.state != 'attached':
                        time.sleep(10)
                        attach_vol.load()
```

I am trying to capture the state of a volume being detached and attached. The last section of the script is where I am getting an error.

```
                detach_vol = volume.detach_from_instance(
                    Device = d,
                    Force = False,
                    InstanceId = i.id,
                    VolumeId = v.id,
                    DryRun = False
                )
                while detach_vol.state != 'detached':
                    time.sleep(10)
                    detach_vol.load()
                
                vol_id = vol.id
                attach_vol = volume.attach_to_instance(
                    VolumeId = vol_id,
                    Device = d,
                    InstanceId = i.id,
                    DryRun = False
                )
                
                while attach_vol.state != 'attached':
                    time.sleep(10)
                    attach_vol.load()
```

This is the error I am getting for the detach section. If I comment out the while statement and use `time.sleep(180)` it will get to the attach section and essentially get the same error as the detach block.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmoorhead\bin\EC2-Vol-Encryption.py", line 131, in <module>
    while detach_vol.state != 'detached':
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'state'
```

I have tried using `response['responsemetadata']['httpstatuscode']` instead of the while statement but haven't been able to get that to work either. Any help could give would be greatly appreicated.

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha
The `detach_vol["state"]` produced an error as well.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmoorhead\bin\EC2-Vol-Encryption.py", line 132, in <module>
    while detach_vol["state"] != "detached":
KeyError: 'state'`

Comment: Then the response didn't contain state. Please refer to my answer and try to use waiters, this might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a functional `while` statement for the detach and attach blocks of code.

```
volume = ec2.Volume(v.id)
detach_vol = volume.detach_from_instance(
    Device = d,
    Force = False,
    InstanceId = i.id,
    VolumeId = v.id,
    DryRun = False
),
while volume.state != "available":
    time.sleep(10)
    volume.load()
volume = ec2.Volume(vol_id)
attach_vol = volume.attach_to_instance(
    VolumeId = vol_id,
    Device = d,
    InstanceId = i.id,
    DryRun = False
)
while volume.state != "in-use":
    time.sleep(10)
    volume.load()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `Volume.detach_from_instance()` returns `dict`, not `Volume` object. You should use `detach_vol["state"]` instead of `detach_vol.state`, that's what error is indicating.
2. boto3 provides waiters for use cases like these. In this case you might use `EC2.Waiter.VolumeAvailable` or `EC2.Waiter.VolumeInUse`, depending on your logic (there is no dedicated "volume is detached" waiter): https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.VolumeAvailable

Comment: Thank you for your response and the link to the boto3 documentation. I came up with a solution that was in line with the other while statements.